# Initialize variables on the fly transformed by sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to utilize variables defined in `.yml` in a shell script. The variable in yaml is in form of `variable: value` . Inside a script I am trying:

```
sed 's/\s*:\s*/=/' *vars.yml*  
echo $variable
```

But `echo` returns nothing. Is it a way to achieve such kind of operation within a shell script?

Comment: Add your .yml file and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `sed` doesn't run the result of the substitution.

Comment: You're not assigning the output of the sed to the $variable either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eval `sed 's/\s*:\s*/=/' *vars.yml*`
echo $variable
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what was missing as far `eval` will execute edited strings, thus creating a variables.

Answer (score 0):

Source the output of your command e.g.

```
$cat vars.yml
var1: value1
var2: value2
var3: value3
$ cat 1.sh
source <(sed 's/\s*:\s*/=/' *vars.yml*)
echo $var1
echo $var2
echo $var3
```

output:

```
value1
value2
value3
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    declare "$(sed 's/[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*/=/' <<< "$line")"
done < file.yml

echo "$var1"
echo "$var2"
```

`file.yml`:

```
var1: value1
var2: value2
```

Output:

```
value1
value2
```

**[Explanation]**

- The `while` loop with `read` reads the input file `file.yml` line by line
  assigning the variable `line` to each record.
- The syntax `declare var=value` creates a variable named `var` then
  assigns it to `value`. The command `declare` accepts not only the literal
  assignment but an expression which is evaluated as an assignment.
  In this case the `sed` command converts the line `var1: value1` into
  `var1=value1` then the `declare` performs the assignment.
- In general it is *not* recommended to use `eval` *unless* you have a full
  and exclusive control over the input file due to a potential security risk.
  Imagine some evil guy adds a line `rm -rf ~/` to the file and it is
  `eval`ed without knowing it.
  Using `declare` is supposed to be less risky than `eval`.

Comment: I afraid it is very hard to understand without some comments to the code

Comment: @l00p thank you for the feedback. I've added an explanation in my answer. Hope it helps.